# how to change color property of all weekdays of all months

Tags: c#, asp.net

`if(e.Day.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
{
    e.cell.BackColor=System.Drwaing.Color.Red;
}`

I am trying this code but it only changes property of single month, I want to change all DayOfweek in all month in the year.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [**`Calendar.DayStyle`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.daystyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to set the style properties ( including color ) for the days in the displayed month.

***Also, note that If you do not specify a different style for the dates NOT in the currently displayed month , these dates will also be displayed using the style specified by the `DayStyle` property.***

```
<asp:Calendar id="calendar1" runat="server">
<DayStyle BackColor="Red"></DayStyle>
</asp:Calendar>
```

In case you want that the dates of other Months are displayed in a different color use: [**`Calendar.OtherMonthDayStyle`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.othermonthdaystyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
<asp:Calendar id="Calendar1" runat="server">
<OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="Green"></OtherMonthDayStyle>
</asp:Calendar>
```

Lastly, as usual you can also set color properties in code. In this case use : [**`Calendar.DayRender`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.dayrender%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event.

```
void Calendar1_DayRender(Object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e) 
      {    
         // Change the background color of the days in other Months
         // to yellow.
         if (e.Day.IsOtherMonth)
         {
            e.Cell.BackColor=System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
         }
         if (!e.Day.IsOtherMonth) //  color to red for current month
         {
            e.Cell.BackColor=System.Drawing.Color.Red;
         }


      }
```

Finally, ***when Navigating through Months in a calendar***, use event: [**`Calendar.VisibleMonthChanged`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.visiblemonthchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which is raised each time the user changes the months.

Markup::

```
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1"
     OnVisibleMonthChanged="Calendar1_VisibleMonthChanged" />
```

Code::

```
protected void Calendar1_VisibleMonthChanged(object sender, MonthChangedEventArgs e)  
    {  
        Calendar1.OtherMonthDayStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;  
        Calendar1.DayStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;  
    }
```

Comment: Boss you are going right but actually what happens when I am go to change month , properties which I set are lost...

Comment: In that case use: " OnVisibleMonthChanged " event of Calendar Control. Updated my answer for the same