# Change prorety of weekday of calender in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
if(e.Day.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
   { e.cell.BackColor=System.Drwaing.Color.Red; }
```

I am trying this code but it only changes property of single month, I want to change all DayOfweek in all month in the year

Comment: You've asked the same question 25 minutes before! [in .net how to change color property of all weekday of all moth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20833657/in-net-how-to-change-color-property-of-all-weekday-of-all-moth)

Comment: there is no answer I found

Comment: It does not mean you should ask it again every 20 minutes. Did you consider that your question is unanswerable? There is not enough data to help you.

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/6897bc/using-calendar-control-in-Asp-Net/

Comment: this code work fine in my calendar,which event you handle this code try it in dayrender event

Answer (score 0):

Error In Above Code if Use Capital  **"C"**  instead of small **"c"** which you have used in your code.

e.**c**ell.BackColor=System.Drwaing.Color.Red;

**My View...**

First of All you have to assign default color to all of the days on calender.
this will set default color to your calender.
`<div><asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" ondayrender="Calendar1_DayRender"> 
<DayStyle BackColor="Beige" />
</asp:Calendar></div>`

While the creating customize calender in asp.net, it fired **DayRender** event.
In **DayRender** Event write this code:-

```
 protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
 {
   if (e.Day.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
     {
   e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }
        }
```

and you will find that all of your month having Red Color at Monday.